# IIS 6.0 Mapped extension not calling dll on local drive

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler

I have a dll that implements IHttpHandler and processes based on querystrings which ultimatley redirects to a specific url. I go to properties for the particular site, add the extension (.handler) in mappings and point it to my dll on the server. 
When i put "/mysiteurl/Index.handler" into the web browser i get a 
HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
To me this means it is not executing the .dll file. Anything that i am missing?